# How to modify the Active Directory security group rules in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, active-directory, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

My goal is to make the active directory security group ingress rules more restrictive. I'm having trouble deleting or modifying the ingress rules that terraform automatically gives this security group.

Using Terraform to set up an active directory automatically spins up an associated security group. I can access this security group using the `security_group_id` attribute reference from the Active Directory resource. I can even add ingress rules to it with:

```
data "aws_security_group" "ad_sg" {
  id = <id of security group>
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "example" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = number
  to_port           = number
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = data.aws_security_group.ad_sg.id
```

And that would add a new ingress rule. Presumably, if I could use terraform to get the id of one of the automatic ingress rules, I could also use `data` to modify it. BUT, I can't figure out any way to get the id's of those rules. I'd expect the SG to have an attribute that returns a list of all its rules' id's, but such a thing doesn't seem to exist.

So, is there any way to get the id's of those automatic security group rules?

Is there any way to just delete all the automatic ingress rules and then just add my own, more restrictive rules from scratch?

Is there some other way to achieve my goal?

From what I can tell, there's no way to change the SG tied to the Active Directory. So it looks like I'm stuck needing to modify the automatic one.

I tried using the code above to add the ingress rules I wanted. I hoped terraform would remove the automatic rules when I did that but it didn't.

Comment: I would try importing the rule into Terraform, see the "import" info at the bottom of this page: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group After it is imported, you can fully control the rules via Terraform.

Answer (score -1):

```
Changing the anywhere source ip of aws active directory default security group rules to the specific ip which we want.
 
You can use aws cli command to delete the existing rules and add similar rule again by modifying the source ip.

You can create terraform null resource and create a shell script to perform actions on the security group rule.
Rule below code in for loop to read each inbound rule and add the values of rule in variable.
```

rules=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids $Security_Group_ID --query "SecurityGroups[].[IpPermissions[*]][0][0][$j]" )

PROTOCOL=$(echo "$rules" | jq -r '.IpProtocol')

FROMPORT=$(echo "$rules" | jq -r '.FromPort')

TOPORT=$(echo "$rules" | jq -r '.ToPort')

IP=$(echo "$rules" | jq -r '.IpRanges[].CidrIp')

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34419222)